# Gatsby blog featured image "cannot return null for non-nullable field WPNodeWithFeaturedImageToMediaItemConnectionEdgeType.node"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, graphql, gatsby

I hope this is the right place to put this, I think it’s an issue with wp-graphql / woographql. Just a bit of background - I’ve been trying to get a WooCommerce / Gatsby project with around 2,200 products to build for over a month now. I initially set up a Lightsail server to deal with the wordpress side of things, but in gatsby-source-wordpress I had to set the requestConcurrency / perPage to 1 or it would crash the server. This was painfully slow, so I’ve moved over to a DigitalOcean server which is faster (requestConcurrency of 2 and a perPage of 5), however it is bringing up a recurring issue I’ve had on previous test WP instances.

I have a custom taxonomy called ‘Collections’. Within this custom taxonomy I have created a ACF Post Object field called ‘featured product’, which is just a WooCommerce product. I’ve created 40+ collections and attached a featured WooCommerce product for each. 
 
I have a custom taxonomy called ‘Collections’. Within this custom taxonomy I have created a ACF Post Object field called ‘featured product’, which is just a WooCommerce product. I’ve created 40+ collections and attached a featured WooCommerce product for each. The data for the featured product pulls through fine, all except for the products featured image, for which it doesn’t seem to have created a node for:

[image]

These products definitely have featured images attached, it just doesn’t seem to be pulling this data through. When I run this on the WP server using GraphiQL you can see the Product does has an image:

[image]

## Deprecated function?

This is also repeatedly appearing in my debug.log:

> [02-Jan-2023 18:42:55 UTC] PHP Deprecated: Function WPGraphQL\Connection\TermObjects::get_connection_config is **deprecated** since version 1.13.0! Use \WPGraphQL\Type\Connection\TermObjects::get_connection_config instead. in /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5383`

## Plugins Used

I’m using the following plugins on the WP server:

- WP Gatsby (v2.3.3)
- WP GraphQL (v1.12.2 - I’ve used so many different versions of this now that I’ve lost count, including the current version, but it has definitely built using this version before )
- WPGraphQL for Advanced Custom Fields (v0.6.1)
- WPGraphQL WooCommerce (WooGraphQL) (v0.11.2) (I have tried all this version and 12.0.0 - this version has built in the past)
- WooCommerce (v7.2.2)
- Advanced Custom Fields Pro (V 6.0.6 )
- Custom Post Type UI (v1.13.1)

And on my local gatsby package.json:

```
{
    "gatsby": "^5.3.3",
    "gatsby-alias-imports": "^1.0.6",
    "gatsby-link": "5.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-algolia": "^1.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-apollo": "^4.0.3",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^3.3.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^5.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^6.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^6.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-s3": "^0.3.8",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^5.3.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^6.3.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-svgr": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-svgr-svgo": "^2.0.0",
    "gatsby-react-router-scroll": "^6.3.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^5.3.1",
    "gatsby-source-wordpress": "7.3.2",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^5.3.1"
}
```

It has built on the AWS server before with this same plugins, it just seems to occur when I moved the server to Digital Ocean - has anyone seen anything like this before?

1. I have tried different combinations of WP-graphQL versions on wordpress, and as well as many other combos of plugins on both gatsby and wordpress.
2. Tried updating gatsby from v4 to v5, and relevant source plugins
3. Had another server on lightsail running fine, but very slow to build.
4. I have deleted the lock file, and restored it afterwards since it made no difference.
5. Interestingly, I've disabled all wordpress plugins, and now the featured images for the blog on the homepage are showing up again.

Comment: I've never used GraphQL and Gatsby, so I might be wrong, but - looking at the screenshots - in the one that fails, you're retrieving the alt text, and in the one that goes through, you're retrieving the slug. Perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm facing the same error.